# Altering a macro to insert info instead of just copying

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Sub test4()

Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim LCopyToCol As Long
Dim arrColsToCopy
Dim c As Range, x As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute


arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 25, 3) 'which columns to copy ?
Set c = Sheets("MasterList").Range("Y5")  'Start search in Row 5
LCopyToRow = 2 'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet4

While Len(c.Value) > 0

    'If value in column Y ends with "2188", copy to Sheet4
    If c.Value Like "*2188" Then

        LCopyToCol = 1
        For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)

            Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = _
                           c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Value

           LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1

        Next x

        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'next row

    End If

    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)

Wend

'Position on cell A5
Range("A5").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

This is what I'm using now to pull columns and paste them in the appropriat eorder. I would like two things to happen.  First, this macro simply pastes the information; I would like to insert the rows of information since i have formulas at the end of columns is the destination sheets.  With just pasting, the info will paste over cells that have formulas in them.  Second, the macro above doesn't carry over any borders; I have the destination sheet set up but when it pastes it loses all the borders(even though the MasterSheet and the destination sheets are bordered).  Maybe inserting will fix that - I'm not sure. But at any rate I would like to insert instead of paste.

Comment: Is there existing data on the destination sheets, or just formulas? If they're all formatted similarly it should be possible to insert the values above the formulas. As to why the borders are not showing: it seems you already have borders applied on the destination sheets - the macro above shouldn't be affecting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you just need to insert a new row in your destination sheet before doing your paste.

So, in the code below I added 1 line that adds a row before the loop which pastes the columns.

```
If c.Value Like "*2188" Then

    LCopyToCol = 1

'--> Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

    For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)
```

Let me know if this looks correct, or if I misunderstood you.

**UPDATE**

To copy formatting, as well, add these 2 lines after the line which copies the values:

```
c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want to do. It transfers the info correctly and inserts to keep the formulas in the destination untouched. However, when it inserts the new lines it take sthe formatting from the row just above where it inserts, which contains all of the column headings. I still have to go through and resize all of the data cells because they are not carrying over their format from the source.

Comment: I updated code to show how to copy formatting too. I haven't tested it, so you may need to alter it somewhat. If this answer solves your problem, please flag it as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. I assume "PastSpecial" should have an "e" in there?  When I put it in I'm getting end of expression errors and/or operation errors. Am I messing up the formatting of the vba or something?

Comment: No, the error is mine. You are right, it should be `PasteSpecial` with an "e". Also, the 3rd line was completely unneeded, so I have removed that. Could you try the code once more? I actually tested it this time :)

Comment: I keep getting an expressions error for the ":=" in both instances in the second line.

Comment: Try removing everything after the `.PasteSpecial` and see if that works

Comment: Strange-it inserts the info fine like before. But it uses the cell sizing for the column title cells; it does not carry down the title column formatting(center, justification, bg color, etc.) in the columns that I am inserting information to; it does, however, carry all of this formatting throughout in the columns that do not have new info brought into them.  So my individual sheets import the first 8 columns, but the last few are not brought in.  The last few columns take on the formatting of the title cells, while the imported cells take the sizing of title cells but format from the source.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the constants xlPasteFormats & xlNone? Could you try changing the line to this: `Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).PasteSpecial -4122, -4142`

Comment: Well, I tried inserting values as above and it gets me no closer to the end result.  One of threee things happens when I tinker around with the lines using this example. One: I get an error pop-up; Two: I get exactly the same format as before(that is, the destination cells are still taking on the format of the column title cells instead of the format from the source- it seems to take the format of the cells one row above where things are being inserted); third to come :)

Comment: Third: it had the same formatting issue above, with the added wrinkle of taking the information in the first cell pasted and populating that information in every cell of the first row thousands of columns out. If that makes sense...

Comment: Well I figured out that if I just add an empty row and change the macro to start copying in row 10 instead of row 9 that it will take the formatting for the empty row instead of the column title cells.                                                                   I am curious, though, if I can change the way I'm doing this.  Instead of having 30ish individual sheets can I just have one template sheet behind the master sheet and then run the macro to open a new sheet based off of the template and insert the information for the macro that I ran?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tips for you:

This code inserts and copies format for me:

```
    Dim rOrigin As Range, rCopyTo As Range

    Set rCopyTo = Selection
    Set rOrigin = Range("A2")

    rCopyTo.Insert xlShiftToRight, rOrigin.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score -1):

from your code, it is very clear that you are only READING values from one sheet and then writing them in another sheet. So to read values generated by formulas, use .TEXT instead of .VALUE

```
myValue = someRange.Text   'reads the output text by the formula but .TEXT is read only so be careful
```

Another thing you might do is use the Copy function that is built in.

```
SomeRange.Copy
```

then go to the sheet you want to paste and do

```
Activesheet.PasteValues
```

or

```
Activesheet.PasteSpecial (use options here to copy formats and so on)
```

Comment: One or both of us is confused I think. My workbook has one master sheet and then @30 individual sheets behind it. The master sheet has no formulas at all; it is only raw data. Each individual sheet has totals and formulas at the bottom of certain columns. When I use the macro above it puts data from the master sheet into the individual ones, but overwrites cells with formulas if the information carries that far.  Instead of just inserting information over all the cells(namely those with my formulas), I want it to insert the rows of data into the individual sheets.